# How do you use javascript/jQuery to rewrite amazon affiliate links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

Basically what I want the script to do, is add my affiliate ID to all Amazon links posted by my users.(Kinda what SO is doing, minus the whole redirect/racking thing)

Here is the code I'm using, and for some reason it's not working.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('a[href*='amazon.com']').each(function() { this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*$/,"") + $.query.load(this.href).set("tag","affID").toString();});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with jQuery, but I think this script may be helpful:
http://petewilliams.info/blog/2009/07/javascript-amazon-associate-link-localiser/

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with your quotes. Try it like this:

```
 $('a[href*="amazon.com"]').each(function() ... etc
```

Notice the difference? The point is that if you use single quotes on the outside, you need to use double quotes on this inside. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jquery plugin it requires.

`$.query.load(this.href)`

this requires the jquery query plugin I suppose.